# TimerTask and Broadcast Receiver onReceive

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, timertask

I have multiple times onReceive triggered with different data for intent during each occurence. I need to combine all the intent data into a list of intents inside a background thread. How can I achieve this?
I tried using timer task, but couldn't achieve the same. Is there any other way? Kindly explain with examples as I don't have much knowledge on background thread
BlockingQueue cannot be used as It will block UI thread for a long time is what I saw in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You could use AsyncTask and do you operations in the doInBackground()-method. Check out [Android's AsyncTask documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask). (Was deprecated in Android R, however)